# DarkReader addon in Chrome: white flashes when tab-switching

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I am using the [DarkReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) addon to make Chrome display pages in a dark theme.

This addon has for a long time been suffering from a persistent bug, whereby white flashes are displayed when switching between tabs or opening new tabs. In contrast to the normal dark theme, this is really tiring for the eyes.

As per the recommendation of the author (who subsequently stopped responding), I installed the Material Simple Dark Grey theme, however this does not fix it. I have the latest version of the addon & of Chrome, thus not sure what else I can do on my side.

Comment: my guess is that you can't because of the way it works (change the colors with custom code) which has to run first, but that is just a guess

Comment: yeah that would make sense..

Answer (score 0):

Use static mode instead of Dynamic. Static produces a lot less white flashes for me.

[image]